# How to get rid of "The following features cannot be saved in macro-free workbooks" in excel 2013?

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros

Every time when I try to save a file, I'm getting the following error message.

[image: Save as Macro-free workbook]

The list of available Add-ins in Excel

[image: Add-ins of excel]
I tested with a fresh file saved with simple word, closed, re-opened and trying to save after changing any letter.

- I ensured there is no content in VBA editor for the file I'm trying
  to save. (No other files opened)
- The default save format in excel option is set to `Excel Workbook`

. How do I get rid of this save as dialog and save as xlsx file by default?

Comment: An Excel Add-In may automatically be modifying your notebook. Please provide a list of all add-ins you have installed in Excel.

Comment: Unable to select all as a list. Attached as snapshot.

Comment: That’s great! Don’t forget to answer your question, you can accept the answer after a day or so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Daniel mentioned, MySQL For Excel add-in is causing this issue. Disabling it and restarting Excel fixed this issue and saves without the nagging dialog.

Comment: This deserves, like, a thousand up-votes. What the prank was the Excel team thinking with this default behavior?

Answer (score 4):

Just to clarify, note that MySQL for Excel is a COM Add-in. In Excel 2013, at the bottom of the Excel Options -> Add-Ins page, click on the Manage drop list, and select COM Add-ins. You will then see the checkbox that needs to be unchecked in order to disable this.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone else that may stumble upon this issue like I did, and the "COM Add-ins" solution didn't help, try this very simple solution:

Just save your file as "xlsm" instead of "xls". Like this:

[image]